# Does the System.Windows.Forms.Timer run on a different thread than the UI?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, timer

I have a main thread that creates a form object which creates and sets a timer to run a function named updateStatus() every minute. But updateStatus() is also called by the main thread at several places.

However, I am not clear about whether or not it will cause any synchronization problems. Does the System.Windows.Forms.Timer in C# run on a different thread other than the main thread?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, the timer events are raised on the UI thread.

You won't have any synchronicity problems. This is the correct version of the timer control to use in a WinForms application; it's specifically designed to do what you're asking. It's implemented under the hood using a standard [Windows timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644900.aspx).

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) confirms this in the Remarks section:

> A Timer is used to raise an event at user-defined intervals. This Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where UI threads are used to perform processing. It requires that the user code have a UI message pump available and always operate from the same thread, or marshal the call onto another thread.
>
> When you use this timer, use the Tick event to perform a polling operation or to display a splash screen for a specified period of time. Whenever the Enabled property is set to true and the Interval property is greater than zero, the Tick event is raised at intervals based on the Interval property setting.

Comment: So the windows timer is running on the main thread, it will be always synchronous and I need not put lock block inside the updateStatus() function . Am I right?

Comment: @user: Yes, that's correct. It runs just like any other event that gets raised on your form, such as the `Paint` or `Load` events. You don't need to lock in those handlers, either.

Answer (score 9):

No, the timer's Tick event is raised from the UI thread by the message loop when it [receives a WM_TIMER message](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Timer.cs,454).  You're always good with that, it can only run when your UI thread is idle.

Answer (score 5):

No.

The whole point of a Windows.Forms Timer is that it runs on the GUI Thread.

Windows (WinForms) runs something called the MessagePump (see `Application.Run()`) and this is what makes the Timer possible.

All your code runs as part of an Eventhandler somehow, and a Timer tick will never 'interrupt' any other event handler.

Comment: Hi, Iam not aware of messagePump . Can you please give some information on it?

Answer (score 4):

The Windows.Forms timer raises the event back on the UI thread, presumably via the sync-context.

If you want a non-UI thread, there are other timers - for example System.Timers.Timer or System.Threading.Timer

Comment: Not quite.  It uses windows messages, so it never leaves the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) it runs on the main UI thread:

> A Timer is used to raise an event at
>   user-defined intervals. This Windows
>   timer is designed for a
>   single-threaded environment where UI
>   threads are used to perform
>   processing. It requires that the user
>   code have a UI message pump available
>   and always operate from the same
>   thread, or marshal the call onto
>   another thread.

Answer (score -1):

I don't want to impeach the reputation of others how has answered, that ***`Windows.Forms.Timer` does always run on GUI thread***, but I have to contradict. :)

I would answer - it depends. **It can be, that `Windows.Forms.Timer` does run on Non-GUI thread!**

`Windows.Forms.Timer` does fire it's `Timer.Tick` event on the thread, where the `Form`, which contains the timer, has been created.

If the form is created on the GUI thread, then the `Timer.Tick` runs on GUI thread, if however `Form` is created on the e.g. some thread XXX from thread pool(what you should avoid), then the `Timer.Tick` runs on this XXX thread.

```
Task.Run(()=>
{
    using (var formWithTimer = new SomeFormWithTimer()) //Form created on worker thread, Tick handled on it.
    {
        formWithTimer.ShowDialog();
    }
});
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman Do you mean, that my answer is wrong?

Comment: @HenkHolterman or do you agree, that `Timer.Tick` can under circumstances run on Non-GUI thread ;)?

Comment: It's not my problem, in answer it's also addressed, that it shouldn't be done. The answer is  here for the complement to emphasize, that `Timer.Tick` not mandatory runs on GUI thread, even if it's not a realistic scenario.