# How to asynchronously wait for x seconds and execute something then?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, sleep, wait

I know there is [`Thread.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) and `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and [`Monitor.Wait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.wait.aspx) in C# and Windows Forms. I just can't seem to be able to figure out how to wait for X seconds and then do something else - without locking the thread.

I have a form with a button. On button click a timer shall start and wait for 5 seconds. After these 5 seconds some other control on the form is colored green. When using `Thread.Sleep`, the whole application would become unresponsive for 5 seconds - so how do I just "do something after 5 seconds"?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `System.Timers` ... I don't think you need to set a CWND timer for what you are trying to do: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcs6ww8(v=VS.90).aspx for an example. It should do the trick.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

(transcribed from Ben as comment)

> just use System.Windows.Forms.Timer. Set the timer for 5 seconds, and handle the Tick event. When the event fires, do the thing.

...and disable the timer (IsEnabled=false) before doing your work in oder to suppress a second.

The Tick event *may* be executed on another thread that cannot modify your gui, you can catch this:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    private void StartAsyncTimedWork()
    {
        myTimer.Interval = 5000;
        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
        myTimer.Start();
    }

    private void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            /* Not on UI thread, reenter there... */
            this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick), sender, e);
        }
        else
        {
            lock (myTimer)
            {
                /* only work when this is no reentry while we are already working */
                if (this.myTimer.Enabled)
                {
                    this.myTimer.Stop();
                    this.doMyDelayedWork();
                    this.myTimer.Start(); /* optionally restart for periodic work */
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Just for completeness: with async/await, one can delay execute something very easy (one shot, never repeat the invocation):

```
private async Task delayedWork()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    this.doMyDelayedWork();
}

//This could be a button click event handler or the like */
private void StartAsyncTimedWork()
{
    Task ignoredAwaitableResult = this.delayedWork();
}
```

For more, see "async and await" in MSDN.

---

more completeness:
Depending on your Framework, there is a good chance you will have `DispatcherTimer` class that can handle the invocation internally (WPF-variants). (finde details in ms docs)

Answer (score 48):

Have you tried

```
public static Task Delay(
    int millisecondsDelay
)
```

You can use like this:

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
```

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 14):

You can start an asynchronous task that performs your action:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    form.Invoke(new Action(()=>DoSomething()));
});
```

**[EDIT]**

To pass the interval in you simply have to store it in a variable:

```
int interval = 5000;
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
{
    Thread.Sleep(interval);
    form.Invoke(new Action(()=>DoSomething()));
});
```

**[/EDIT]**

Answer (score 8):

You can wait UI thread the way you want it to work.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async() =>
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    // it only works in WPF
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        // Do something on the UI thread.
    });
});
```

if you're using .Net Framework 4.5 or higher version, you can use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew` just like below.

```
int millisecondsDelay = 2000;

Task.Run(async() =>
{
    await Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay);

    // it only works in WPF
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        // Do something on the UI thread.
    });
});
```

Comment: making the Ui thread wait can lead to bad UX, why not do that in a different thread

Answer (score 1):

your application hangs because you are invoking the 5 second sleep/wait on the main UI thread. put the sleep/wait/whatever action in a separate thread (actually System.Windows.Forms.Timer should do that for you) and when it completes invoke the action that turns some control green. remember to check InvokeRequired. here's a short sample (SetText can be called from another thread, if it is the call will instead be invoked on the main UI thread where the textbox is on):

```
private void SetText(string text)
{
// InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
// calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
// If these threads are different, it returns true.
if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
{    
    SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
    this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
}
else
{
    this.textBox1.Text = text;
}
}
```

I took the sample from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (well worth a read!).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at it wrong.
Click the button, it kicks off a timer with an interval of x seconds. When those are up it's eventhandler executes the task.

So what don't you want to happen.

While the x seconds are elapsing.?

While The task is executing?

If for instance it's you don't want the button to be clicked until delay and task are done. Disable it in the button click handler, and enable it on task completion.

If all you want is a five second delay prior to the task, then you should pass the start delay to the task and let it take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

*@eFloh in the post marked as answer said:*

> The Tick event may be executed on another thread that cannot modify
>   your gui, you can catch this ...

That is not what the docs say.
You are using a System.Windows.Forms.Timer in your example code.
That is a *Forms.Timer*.
According to the C# docs the Timer events are raised on the UI thread.

> This Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where
>   UI threads are used to perform processing. It requires that the user
>   code have a UI message pump available and always operate from the same
>   thread ...

Also see [stackoverflow post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694469/does-the-system-windows-forms-timer-run-on-a-different-thread-than-the-ui)