# Form Changing Before Other Commands Are Executed

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have this little bit of code here...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text==("Tim The Enchanter") && textBox1.Text==("cave100"))
        {
            label2.Visible = true;
            label2.Text = ("Correct");
            label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            this.Hide();
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Visible = true;

        }
    }
```

It is basically a very primitive login screen!

Everything works except for the fact that the form changes to form2 before the label2 text can be seen. I tried to fix this by adding a system wait comand but instead this comes through before the text can be displayed. Once again I am back to where I started.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never use `Thread.Sleep` for waiting purposes in WinForms.
It blocks GUI thread and your label is not updated / seen by a user.

Of course, there are many workarounds to do it, you can read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112305/how-to-asynchronously-wait-for-x-seconds-and-execute-something-then).

The easiest one is to use C# 5.0 `async` / `await` functionality:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2.Text==("Tim The Enchanter") && textBox1.Text==("cave100"))
    {
        label2.Visible = true;
        label2.Text = ("Correct");
        label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        this.Hide();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `Thread.Sleep` from the UI thread in winforms.

A click event handler needs to do its work and return quickly, because all the form drawing, responding to resize events, responding to user-input, etc is all happening on the same thread. This is the reason you don't see the form repaint itself - it doesn't get a chance, because you suspended the thread it would use to do that.

You need to do this in a more "event-driven" way. For example, you could add a `Timer` control to the form, with a timeout of 1000ms, and an `Elapsed` handler that shows/hides the forms.

Then your button handler just sets the timer `Enabled` to `true`, and exits.

Remember to stop the timer in the timer's event handler though!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text==("Tim The Enchanter") && textBox1.Text==("cave100"))
        {
            label2.Visible = true;
            label2.Text = ("Correct");
            label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

            new Timer{Enabled=true,Interval=100}.Tick += (s,e) =>
            {
              ((Timer)s).Dispose();
              this.Hide();
              Form2 form2 = new Form2();
              form2.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

It will give the OS a chance to make modifications to the UI before it shows the instance of `Form2`

Comment: Yeldar Kurmangaliyev's answer is probably the best, although my answer might be needed if you don't have C# 5.0.