# Best practice for waiting for event being fired in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

For example, we have some action and method, on which the event is being subscribed:

```
    // some response property
    static _response {get; set;}

    // client sends the post request
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SomeAction(Model someModel)
    {
        if (someModel != null)
        {
            // here we subscribing on event
            SomeEventHandler.Subscribe(MethodBeingFired)
            // here we must wait for firing the event and check if event has been fired
            if (eventBeenFired) return Json(new { response = _response })
            // or if some wait time's out
             return Json(new { error = "Time for executing your request is out" });
          }
    }

    public void MethodBeingFired(SomeEventResult result)
    {
       // here we have to notify the action in a current thread that event has been fired
       eventBeenFired = true;
      _response = result.Response;
    }
```

I guess that the code scheme above is pretty clear and understandable. My action should wait some time for capturing the event and return the response or error.

Comment: Possible answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112305/how-to-asynchronously-wait-for-x-seconds-and-execute-something-then

Comment: @Matt, yeap, but I'm not sure if this is the best practice

Comment: If you need to have custom timeout, I think you need to use some kind of a timer either way.

Comment: @LabLab The design you are proposing is bad for web based asp.net mvc. Read up on SignalR and see how it fits into your design

Comment: @Nkosi, you are right, but it's tightly tied on HTTP requests rather than sockets

Comment: You'll need to create your own class to waits until the message is received or cancel if its timeout. Events like this aren't very good for web development unless you use websocket that allows the server to contact the client.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, I believe you should [delegates & event handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/)

Moreover, you can;

- use  [queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.8) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531438/c-triggering-an-event-when-an-object-is-added-to-a-queue)
- use a message-queueing software like  [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html)  and you may set your controllers to act like both a publisher and a consumer.