# System.Windows.Forms Timer is not functioning when a thread is running on main

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, mutex, ui-thread

I would like to ask anyone of you if you have tried this kind of scenario. I developed a windows application in c#. In main Program (Program.cs) I added a thread mutex just to multitask many operations executed under it.

```
//under Program.cs
public static FormOneInstance frmOneInstance;
    static void Main()
    {
         t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CreateInputOutput));
         t.Start();
    }
    public static void CreateInputOutput()
    {
                try
                {
                    mutex.WaitOne(); 
                    ExecuteManyOperationsHere(); 
                }
                finally
                {
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                    Thread.CurrentThread.Abort(); //Has ThreadAbortException here
                    t = null;
                }
      }



  public static void ExecuteManyOperationsHere()
    {
      frmOneInstance  =new FormOneInstance (); //this has lot of execution on formLoad that includes ShowSummary()
    }
```

And on my other Form FormOneInstance class, I used System.Windows.Forms Timer

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ShowSummary();
        }
```

Now, I want to separate the thread in main and UI.
Thanks!

Comment: You need message loop for this timer... Note that it is really unclear why you pick that timer for console app... and what code with `mutex.WaitOne` should represent. It may be good idea to read [MCVE] guidance to improve the question.

Comment: This is not a console app. why message loop is needed?

Comment: Mutexes are a synchronization mechanism for two or more threads to access a shared resource at the same time. I don't see the mutex being used by more than one thread and I don't see what resource is being synchronized. If timer1_Tick is being used to show progress/results from the other thread then it is not likely to be that easy. Are you familiar with Background Workers?

Comment: Yes, I used that before but my application still hangs up. So, when I tried using mutex, it runs smoothly

Comment: @user34660 I already updated my post.

Comment: It is still not clear what your requirements are.

Comment: All i wanted is to separate the thread in main and UI forms

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Forms Timer runs on the ui thread and there is only one see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694469/does-the-system-windows-forms-timer-run-on-a-different-thread-than-the-ui).

See for example the [Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN

You could use a timer which doesn't this stuff. but be sure to invoke back, to the ui thread when the timer code wants to change values that are shown in the ui

```
myTimer= new Timer( handleTimer, null, timerIntervall, Timeout.Infinite );
```

Then you can create a method which invokes your **CreateInputOutput** method on the ui thread in order to show a new ui element

```
public void handleTimer(object State)
{
// PLace here the blocking code which shoudl not block the ui
this.invoke(...)  // here you can call the method which should be run un the ui thread. Like creating new forms
}
```

}

for more details see also this post about [threading timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796148/working-with-system-threading-timer-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not clear what your requirements are, I will assume that what you really want to use is a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx). The following also have samples.

[BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress Method (Int32, Object) (System.ComponentModel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Walkthrough: Multithreading with the BackgroundWorker Component (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx?cs-save-lang=1)

[How to: Run an Operation in the Background](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hybbz6ke(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1)